# SQL Server Agent newly added job steps get deleted when modifying maint plan

Tags: sql-server

Scenario in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio:

1. Create maintenance plan (Management -> Maint Plans -> Maint Plan Wizard (i.e. TestBackup)
2. Under SQL Server Jobs, right click the TestBackup job
3. Add a few a new step (properties -> steps -> new) and save
4. Under maintenance plans, right click TestBackup, make a change, and save

Now if you back to TestBackup job under SQL Server Jobs, the new step that got created is no longer there!

Comment: Maybe create the job without the maintenance plan wrapper? Or do those additional tasks in a different job. It might be as simple as Object Explorer hasn't refreshed or a bug in an older version of SSMS, but...

Comment: Things like this is why I don't use maintenance plans :/ [Like it will change ownership too](https://thelonelydba.wordpress.com/2012/08/21/changes-in-maintenance-plan-overwriting-sql-job-ownership/). And if i'm not mistaken,  saving a main plan overwrites the job completely. I'll find documentation for that.

Comment: What I was trying to do was run the job.  If it's successful, execute some sql.  If it's not success execute some other sql.   Seems so easy, until you go back and tweak the maint plan. egads.

Comment: Is `TestBackup` job some kind of built-in job?   Maybe the maintenance plan tool drops and rebuilds it.   Sounds more like a DBA question than a developer question.

Comment: I understand what you mean, just remember those are SSIS packages on the back end so this isn't super surprising. But, you could check out [Ola's scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/)... they do a TON :) and can help you ditch the maint plan all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too Long To Comment

It has been suggested by many that you shouldn't edit a maintenance plan via any other means other than the designer. This includes editing the "Jobs" or sub-plans which get created by the SSIS package which is at the core of the maintenance plan. [Brad McGehee](https://bradmcgehee.com/) (SQL Server MVP, MCITP, MCSE+I, MCSD, and MCT) talks about this in his book [*Brad's Sure Guide to SQL Server Maintenance Plans*](http://assets.red-gate.com/community/books/sql-server-maintenance-plans-brad-ebook.pdf), specifically starting on p.74. Here is one exerpt:

> p.264-265 Throughout this book, I have made occasional reference to
>   the fact that you should use the Maintenance Plan Designer to modify
>   Maintenance Plans created using the Maintenance Plan Wizard. This is
>   because the Maintenance Plan Wizard offers no way to modify a
>   Maintenance Plan after it has been created, so the only way to change
>   it safely is to use the Maintenance Plan Designer.A Maintenance Plan,
>   created using either the Maintenance Plan Wizard or the Maintenance
>   Plan Designer, is implemented "behind the scenes" as a single SQL
>   Server Integration Services (SSIS) package, executed using one or more
>   SQL Server Agent jobs. While it is possible to manually modify a
>   Maintenance Plan by modifying its SQL Server Agent job, it is not
>   recommended, as there is a strong likelihood of breaking the plan.
>   Instead, always make your changes to a Maintenance Plan using the
>   Maintenance Plan Designer

Others have reported similar issues where the [ownership of their subplans changed](https://thelonelydba.wordpress.com/2012/08/21/changes-in-maintenance-plan-overwriting-sql-job-ownership/) (were overwritten). Likewise, one user [reported the same behavior you have witnessed](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlsandwiches/2011/06/12/don-t-touch-that-maintenance-plan-job/) by editing the sub-plan directly. He avoided this by adding a step in his Maintenance Plan to `Execute SQL Server Agent Job Task` which fired off a job with his custom step. Notice that this aligns with Brad's advice, and those of others, to only edit these tasks via the Maintenance Plan Designer.

You will also notice that if you edit your Maintenance Plan, and change nothing (but, perhaps the description of the overall plan) and then save it, the modified time on your sub-plan which was **unrelated** to the change, would reflect this same time. Meaning, it too was changed. Likewise, deleting a maint plan delete's it bound agent jobs.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  It was much appreciated!

Comment: No sweat @FatFingers and definitely check out Ola's scripts. They are AWESOME and he keeps them updated.